# Dynamically construct empty rows for for data elements expand in asp.net (or html)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create a sort of template for my project, which is just the main content (not a master page, and not user control) for several similar pages that I need.

I'm very new to asp.net and to HTML, so I'm sure you guys can help me.

The pattern I want to achieve looks something like this (did this in paint, so excuse me):

[image]

At the bottom there's a partial code of a form I'm trying to build (it has only the upper gridview and details view for now), but you can see my problem in the screenshot I took (the erased row has personal data): the gridview (and the detailsview) drops lower then the "SECOND CENTERED SUBTITLE". How do I keep empty lines depending on the amount of rows in the gridview? 
Can I set a maximum amount of rows for the gridview without loosing data?

I also add a part of the css file which is used on this form.

THANKS!

[image]

**`.aspx` file (main content- after the master code):**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="maincontent2headers">Create New Sale</div>
    <div><br /> </div>
    <div class="maincontent2leftsubtitles" > Select customer </div>
    <div class="maincontent2rightsubtitles"> Custumer's Details </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="floatleft">
        <asp:GridView ID="SelectCustomerGridView" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="Customer_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" 
                ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_ID" 
                    HeaderText="Customer_ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Customer_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" 
                    HeaderText="First_Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" 
                    HeaderText="Last_Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Customer_ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name] FROM [Customers]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright">

    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px"
        Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="Customer_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" 
            ForeColor="#284775" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_ID" 
                HeaderText="Customer_ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Customer_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" 
                HeaderText="First_Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" 
                HeaderText="Last_Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" 
                SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="eMail" HeaderText="eMail" 
                SortExpression="eMail" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" 
            ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" 
            ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Customer_ID] = @Customer_ID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SelectCustomerGridView" 
                DefaultValue="NULL" Name="Customer_ID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div  class="maincontent2centeredsubtitles">
        second subtitle here</div>
    <br />

    <div>
    <div class="floatleft">put here to float to the left</div>
    <div class="floatright">put here to float to the right</div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <center>place to show the results (delete the center tags)</center>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div >
    <center>buttons to proceed (delete the canter tags)</center>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Part of the `css` that concerns this code:

```
.floatleft
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.floatright
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.maincontent2headers
{
    font-family: 'Arial Black';
    font-size: xx-large; 
    color: #465767;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    width:auto;
}

.maincontent2centeredsubtitles
{
    font-family: 'Arial Black'; 
    font-size: small; 
    color: #465767; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.maincontent2leftsubtitles
{
    font-family: 'Arial Black'; 
    font-size: small; 
    color: #465767; 
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;

}

.maincontent2rightsubtitles
{
    font-family: 'Arial Black'; 
    font-size: small; 
    color: #465767; 
    float:right;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.centeredtext
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself (if anyone read this in the future):

I used the css `clear` property for the "Second subtitle here", and set it to `both`.

this way, no floating objects are allowed in the left and the right areas of the title.